# ASP.NET Boilerplate Entity commit immediately

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've started working with Entities within ASP.NET Boilerplate. Im trying to get my entities to commit to the database immediately but i cant seem to do it.

I am calling `await CreateAsync(EntityDto);`.

I've tried overriding the CreateAsync within my controller to include `CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();`.

I have also tried to wrap the code in a unit of work.

```
        using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
        {
            var entityDto = await CreateAsync(entityDto);
            await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
        }
```

But it never seems to commit to the database immediately.

Any help would be much apricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ABP's [Conventional Unit of Work](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#conventional-unit-of-work-methods) is scoped around your Controller action and [The unit of work is ambient](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#a-unit-of-work-method-calls-another).

You should require a new unit of work with `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew`:

```cs
using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    var entityDto = await CreateAsync(entityDto);
    await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
}
```

Alternatively, you can suppress the unit of work with `TransactionScopeOption.Suppress`:

```cs
using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
{
    var entityDto = await CreateAsync(entityDto);
    await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
}
```